# How to implement custom serializer

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I'm using Scala 2.12, implementing some producers and consumer with this library:

```
"org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "2.4.1"
```

For both key and value I'm using `classOf[StringDeserializer]`.

Let's say every message is a json string of a case class like this:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int, id: UUID)
```

So `value` in every message would be something like this:

```
{"name":"Joe", "age": ...}
```

How can I write customer serializer for this?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I write customer serializer

You'd implement the interface...

```
class MySerializer extends Serializer[Person] { 
    override def serialize(String topic, Person p): Array[Byte] { ... }
}
```

> Let's say every message is a json string

Kafka already has a [`JSONSerializer`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/json/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/json/JsonSerializer.java) class you can use

Or you can use the ones provided by [Confluent](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/json-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/KafkaJsonSerializer.java) or [Spring-Kafka](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#json-serde).

Otherwise, `StringSerializer` will work fine if you pre-serialize the data before producing